# Windows 10 shutdown Failure. black screen but key lights still on.

Tags: drivers, shutdown

I have uninstalled and reinstalled the Intel(R) Management Engine Interface driver, but it wont re-roll to an earlier version. For some the earlier driver version seems to be a solution for the problem. I have gone into power management to turn off fast startup, but there is no option for me to do so. I guess my main question is how do you rollback a driver to an earlier version? And where else i might locate the fast startup option to turn it off because currently it is not in the spot that everyone says it is in (power options > choose what the power button does/ (system settings) > change settings that are currently unavailable > uncheck fast startup (this option is not there) .

Answer (score -1):

There should be an option within your BIOS boot options to enable/disable Fast/Quick Boot. Give this a try.